# Returning no records with Doctrine Extensions Translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using Doctrine Extensions Translatable to translate my Article entity.

$article = $em->getRepository("ModelBundle:Article")->find(1);

Doctrine Extensions provide two options if a field is not translated according to my research.

- Keeping the original value (default locale)

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    translation_fallback: true
```

- Displaying a blank value

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    translation_fallback: false
```

I want my repository to return a null value (no record at all) if one or many fields are not translated.

I know that it’s possible to check this with statements like:

if ($article->getTitle === ''), however I will have to do it in dozens of places.